# dc.js rowChart with bars going from right to left

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

The whole question is in the title really.
For a `rowChart` in the `dc.js` library how does one make the bars go from right to left instead of the default behaviour which is the opposite ?

Default behaviour:

[image: default left to right]

I have also created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/z300hhbv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot negative values the zero axis will be on the right side and the bars will grow to the left.

```
speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    return -d.Speed * d.Run / 1000;
});
```

[image: leftward rows]

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/zg4pL994/1/)

EDIT: It's better to change the `valueAccessor`:

```
.valueAccessor(kv => -kv.value)
```

this leaves the value alone, so you don't have to change the label function, and it preserves the greatest-to-least ordering:

[image: greatest-to-least]

As for aligning the labels right, this isn't as easy as it may sound, because in SVG, all positions are measured from the upper right. To do it perfectly would require a contribution to the library (if you are up for it ;), but if you don't mind the labels showing up after the bars have animated, you can do it by watching events on the chart:

```
var first = true;
chart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    if(first)
            chart.selectAll('text.row')
                .attr('visibility', 'hidden');
    else
            chart.selectAll('text.row')
            .attr('x', function(d) {
                return +d3.select(this.parentNode)
                  .select('rect').attr('width')-10;
            })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'end')

    first = false;
});
chart.on('renderlet', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('text.row')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return +d3.select(this.parentNode)
              .select('rect').attr('width')-10;
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

This hides the first time the bars are animated, then when they are complete, it moves them to a position determined from the width of the `rect` that is a sibling element inside the same `g`, and anchors them at the end. (I.e. it right-aligns them. This probably would break in RTL languages, but I suspect the labels are already broken in those languages.)

It also sets sets the position at the beginning of each subsequent redraw, to erase where the chart wants to put them.

[image: labels on right]
[Revised fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zg4pL994/12/)

I suspect that there will still be artifacts when the data changes. In order to do this right, the labels would have to be animated in order to always match the bar width as it is changing! Or else they would have to be moved out of the parent `g` so that their position is absolute and not affected by the bar width.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then I have to do a `label` function that takes into account the fact that I am showing the opposite of my values. Cool that should work, will give it a try. Also, since I have you here, the links to the base fiddle on the `dc.js` website are not functional anymore because `d3` has been updated on cdn but the fiddle themselves still reference the old naming convention.

Comment: Yes you are right, you will have to hack the label function too. Kind of lame but it's hard to think of a nice general way to include it in the library. Thank you for pointing out the broken fiddles!! I knew that most of my old fiddles had died because they pointed to dc.js without a version. But this is more serious! Will fix in 3.0.2.

Comment: So i've got it working (https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/zg4pL994/3/) but how would you make the labels stick to 0 instead of going to the end of the bars ? I have tried hacking the `.labelOffsetX` option but to no avail.

Comment: It's not all that easy because everything in SVG is relative to the upper-left corner of things. That's probably why this has never been added to the library. I added a hacky attempt above, as well as a better way to invert the values without changing the data.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I used the `valueAccessor` before you pointed to it actually. Made more intuitive sense. You still need to add a line to format the `xAxis()` ticks. I am unfortunately not proficient enough in JS to be able to tackle the general issue. If you point me to where it is calculated I could still have a look though (and then add a `.alignLabels("right")` option for the rowChart I guess ?